# Переключение песни в html audio

Tags: javascript, html, аудио

Есть обычный html тег `<audio>`

```
<audio controls>
<source id='sourceSong' src='/web/uploads/music/1.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>
```

Как сделать переключение песни? Я пытался с помощью js / jquery менять `src` ,
но не получается. Src меняется, а с элементом ничего не происходит( Помогите плз!

```
$("#sourceSong").attr('src', '/web/uploads/music/2.mp3');
```

Comment: Так надо потом `play()` сделать

Comment: А не кинете ссылку на функцию `play()`, а то я ее не нашел)?

Comment: $("#sourceSong").parent()[0].play();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализация, которая используется во многих html5-аудио плеерах, следующая: для каждого трека, который необходимо воспроизвести, заранее подготавливается или позже добавляется на страницу отдельный audio-тег с заранее заданным src. При помощи js воспроизводимый audio останавливается и выполняется play на другом.